# Data type error with scan

Tags: r

I have a .dat file of time series data for options so it includes trade date and expiration date, in addition to the price data for which I want to do timeseries analysis in R.
I am new to R, so I have been following some of the examples online. in my attempt to upload the data as a data-frame, I tried the scan(), but I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '2010-Aug-09,2011-Aug-19,C00026000,0.23985,5.53,0.999999,0.00712328'
```

I understand it is expecting real but I need to enter the dates and the option ticker to make sense of the time series, so can someone give me some guidance on how I go about it.thx.

Comment: Why not just use `read.csv`? And what does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Fixed the title to match the question content.

Comment: ok thanks, let me work with that. @Richie, thanks for correcting the title :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scan requires that you specify the contents of the data; by default it assumes that you are just reading in numbers (which you aren't).

As per Joran's comment, `read.csv` (or `read.table`) is much more user friendly for reading in data frames from file.  Use that instead.

Answer (score 11):

I'll reiterate that `scan` is a pretty low-level function and in almost every case you're better off using `read.table` or `read.csv`.

But to get scan to work on what I am inferring is in your `.dat` file, you need to tell it (at least) what the field separator is and what the data types are. So something like:

```
scan('temp.dat',sep=',',what=list('character','character','character','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric'))
```

would do the trick.